# Sencha Touch 2: How to create History feature?

Tags: sencha-touch-2

Example: http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/where-to-eat-free-gps-restaurant/id468661982?mt=8
On the tab bar, there's a "Recents", which will record anything you've viewed.

I'd like to create that for my web app, a shopping guide. Users check out various shops from a list, and when they select to view a shop, it'll be recorded. Sort of like a browser History.

I know it'd be too much to ask for an entire code, so can someone just push me in the right direction? Like explain to me how to get started, what I need to know or better yet point me to any examples out there (I've yet to find one)

Thanks!

Comment: Your question has almost no information about what you already have. If it wasn't tagged as a Sencha Touch question, people wouldn't even have any idea what technology or language you are working with or what platform it's supposed to work on. Please rephrase your question and provide more info.

Comment: What info do you need precisely? I have searched for examples and yet to find one that has the feature Recently Viewed.

Comment: By "info" I mean anything that falls under the umbrella of "This is what I have done so far". You say you have "searched for examples". What did you search for? Right now it's completely unclear what it is you want. For instance you say you didn't find "one that has the feature Recently Viewed". What "one"? Application? Website? Programming language? Framework? There's no way to tell. Read this if you want more info about what your question is missing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: Sorry I don't even know how to start asking. I'm not an advanced coder. Like I said. Sencha Touch 2. A shopping guide app that I've already managed to create tab panels, lists, nestedlists etc. Right now one of the features that I'd like to add is a History feature. I have no idea how to even start to add a History feature. Something like browsing history. If I am clear, if I have the keywords maybe I can do the searching?

Comment: Please edit your question to reflect this. Describe in detail what you have, and what you want.

Comment: If you need a basic Sencha Touch example: https://github.com/FrancisShanahan/SenchaTouch2MVCHelloworld

Comment: LOL thanks but not that basic. I've a working prototype now, one that uses the sencha touch 2 MVC just need to add features. I'll include an example, albeit a native app one.

Comment: @Jayraj, the [ask] can be linked to as `[ask]` [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting). Roxercise; it's generally expected that you ask a specific question that has an answer and shows [how you have tried to solve the problem yourself](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/). Obviously that's not always possible but some attempt at answer your own question is always appreciated by those who might be able to answer.

Comment: Sorry I realize I'm being vague, and not showing some coding examples of my work. But instead of bug fixes, I really need a push as to how to start this Recent/History feature.

Answer (score 2):

Try using `Ext.data.Store` in Sencha Touch to create a data store of your user's browsing history. When they view a shop, add it as an item in the store. You will need to create an `Ext.data.Model` to describe a view action. You can also sync stores with your backend. It's all in the Sencha Touch Docs.

The MVC example uses a store (I think) if you need an example.

Comment: You're right, I wasn't looking hard enough. Thanks for the follow through though. I'll post my work later.

Answer (score 1):

you can look at Sencha Touch 2 getting started documentation. there are [History Support](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/guide/history_support) section. Hope this help. good luck ...